# Go back to previous application Iphone Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, swift3

I Have two Apps and one call the other App using **UIApplication.shared.openURL**

In second app there is a button in status bar to back to previous app.
There is some function to back to previous application without pressing this button in status bar?

Image example. This button.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34462796/is-it-possible-to-go-back-to-previous-open-app-programatically-in-ios)

Comment: Thanks for answer @AdityaSrivastava but a want a solution in Swift

Answer (score 0):

You might try seeing what happens if your second app does an openURL back to your first app.  Does iOS really nest back and forth or does it simply remove the "Back to " button?  Worth a try!

Comment: I put openURL and it's back to the previous app. How can I remove back button in the first app?

Comment: Once back in your first app, try having the first app forward to itself with another openURL.  Just speculating here...  otherwise, am out of ideas.